# Off-site payment method from the terminal

Tags: commerce

Just wondering if it is possible to setup an off-site payment from the terminal. I've already created a custom module for a custom offsite payment method for standard user checkout process. I also need to add this option to the terminal so it can be used by Admins when creating an order in the backend

Is that doable?

Just to note, I'm a Drupal beginner so I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Have you thought to add Drush integration to your module, or using Drush is not one of your possibilities?

Comment: It is a possibility to use Drush. What do you have in mind tho?

Comment: Drush is a command-line tool; if your module integrates with Drush, you could have a command line like `drush off-payment [...]`.

Comment: But can you explain why this way? Do you mean by this Drush is the only method to do an offsite call like this from the terminal? I didn't use Drush to do frontend checkout payment. Would prefer to keep the code consistent and not have terminal and frontend working differently. So can you explain why you suggest Drush?

Comment: Because Drush is the command line tool for Drupal...but I suspect there's a misunderstanding here - what is your definition of "terminal" in this question? As programmers/sysadmins we obviously think you're referring to a command line terminal, but I get the feeling that's not what you meant? Please clarify

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used the term terminal because there is a param in commerce_payment_method_info hook named 'terminal' (either true or false). Switching it causes the payment method becomes available when you create an order from the backend

Comment: Yeah, the question pertains to the payment terminal defined by the Payment module in Drupal Commerce, not Terminal the command line tool for OS X. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't doable, unfortunately, because it would require a redirection process that is currently only supported by the checkout form. If it's a requirement for a site, I'd pursue a way for administrators to use the checkout form like a normal customer and submit payment being redirected from there instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'd very much like to pursue such a way. Is there one tho through an existing module?

Comment: Nope. You'd have to write it, but ultimately I think you would have a much easier time doing what I recommended above re: the checkout form.